# Custom sorting on UltraWebGrid - ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

How can I accomplish custom sorting on the Infragistics UltraWebGrid?
I've tried to hadle the SortColumn event and it works, however, whenever I click the column header, the columns are sorted via JavaScript in the website before the event is fired in the server side? How do I stop the grid from sorting in the client?

Thanks,

Leandro Fernandez

Answer (score 1):

1. Click "Edit Data Structure" of the UltraWebGrid
2. Click "Basic Settings"
3. Click "Feature Picker"
4. Click "allow sorting"
5. Click "sorting on server"

This should solve your problem.